# WCF Project library

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf

I want to migrate my WCF serivce from WebSite App_Code folder to project library. 
As far as I know, WCF library is able to read web config about service model, so the only action I did was following:
1 - Create new project library and put all code about wcf from app_code to it.
2 - Modify web config in order to point at service class with full qualified name (namespace + class name)
3 - Modify svc file in order to point at service class instance with full qualifide name.

However, my service is not running anymore. I'm using ws-httpbinding with custom validator, but it seems my service expect a basic http binding.
The error I'm struggling with appears like this: 
the request of message must be protected, such as required by a contract operation ('IMyService','http://tempuri.org/'). The protection must be implemented by ('BasicHttpBinding','http://tempuri.org/') binding.

**@@EDIT:**

My Web.Config:

```
  <system.serviceModel>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="MyBehavior">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
          <serviceCredentials>
            <userNameAuthentication userNamePasswordValidationMode="Custom" customUserNamePasswordValidatorType="MyWcfNamespaceOfMyDLL.MyCustomValidator" />
            <serviceCertificate findValue="localhost" x509FindType="FindBySubjectName" storeLocation="LocalMachine" storeName="My" />
          </serviceCredentials>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <bindings>
      <wsHttpBinding>
        <binding name="MyBinding" maxBufferPoolSize="1000000000" maxReceivedMessageSize="1000000000" messageEncoding="Mtom">
          <security mode="Message">
            <message clientCredentialType="UserName" />
          </security>
        </binding>
      </wsHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <services>
      <service behaviorConfiguration="MyBehavior" name="MyServiceName">
        <endpoint address="" binding="wsHttpBinding" contract="MyWcfNamespaceOfMyDLL.IMyServiceName" bindingConfiguration="MyBinding">
          <identity>
            <dns value="localhost" />
          </identity>
        </endpoint>
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
      </service>
    </services>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
  </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

This is my svc file inside web site root:

```
<%@ ServiceHost Language="C#" Debug="true" Service="MyWcfNamespaceOfMyDLL.MyServiceName" %>
```

Finally, service contrat inside my dll appears like this:

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IMyService
{
    [OperationContract(ProtectionLevel=System.Net.Security.ProtectionLevel.EncryptAndSign)]
    string DoSomething();
}

public class MyServiceName : IMyService
{
   public string DoSomething();
}

public class MyValidator : UserNamePasswordValidator
    {
// simple validation
}
```

Any idea?

Comment: Should probably show your web.config code.

Comment: You should post your code - the config's servicemodel section and the servicecontract.

Comment: Just edited everythings..

Comment: You may be having a problem with the service contract's default namespace - http://tempuri.org.

Comment: I've not idea. Have you something to suggest me to solve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've solved.
The problem was about dll name missing on web config.

I had to change my config as following:

First:

```
<userNameAuthentication userNamePasswordValidationMode="Custom" 
      customUserNamePasswordValidatorType="="MyWcfNamespaceOfMyDLL.MyCustomValidator", MyDllName" />
```

Second:

```
<services>
      <service behaviorConfiguration="MyBehavior" 
               name="MyWcfNamespaceOfMyDLL.MyServiceName">
        <endpoint address="" binding="wsHttpBinding"
                  contract="IMyServiceName" bindingConfiguration="MyBinding">
          <identity>
```

I think everyone could begin crazy..!!

Well, as you can see, I had to:

- Specify DLL name on userNameAuthentication tag.
- Specify namespace name on attribute name of service tag.
- Remove specification about namespace name on contract attribute of endpoint tag.

Ok I 've solved, but I'm a bit worried for the next future ..!!

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that the problem comes from the service and not *from the client* ?

Can you show us how do you call this service ?

> the request of message must be protected, such as required by a contract operation ('IMyService','http://tempuri.org/'). The
>   protection must be implemented by
>   ('BasicHttpBinding','http://tempuri.org/') binding.

As said [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.servicecontractattribute.protectionlevel.aspx),

> If the binding does not support security (such as BasicHttpBinding),
>   the effective System.Net.Security.ProtectionLevel is
>   ProtectionLevel.None for the whole contract. The result is that
>   depending upon the endpoint binding, clients can require different
>   message or transport level security protection even when the contract
>   specifies ProtectionLevel.None.

This error message suggests you are calling the service with a basicHttpBinding with no ProtectionLevel.

Also, the contract in your Web.config `IMyServiceName` is not the same that in your code 'IMyService' or in the error message.

Comment: IMyServiceName and IMyService has been my keying in error only..Yes, I'm deal with you, but I'm not able to add service reference from any client. Also, I would remeber you I've got this problem after I have moved service code into dll project. When my service was whole in asp.net, all worked fine. I'm using server certificate for protection, but I repeat again, if I undo all modification and I put my service Interface in app_code, all works fine.